# Find minimal weight of a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm, weighted, weighted-graph

I am trying to find an algorithm, which can find the minimal total weight of a given tree.

I am given a tree and a weight of all nodes (each node can have a different weight). 
For example in this graph, where each node has weight 1:
[tree with weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PwTM.jpg)

Then I am given a set of at least two numbers, let's call them X.
For example X: 2, 3, 4, 5.
Each node is assigned one X value, while no two adjacent nodes can have the same X value. 
In result, each node has a total weight of X * weight.
After adding total weight of all nodes, we get the total weight of the tree.
[tree result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c14jk.jpg)

The goal is to find an algorithm, which can find one such distribution of X values, so that we get a minimal weight of the tree.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: write about approaches you tried so far and where you are stuck?

Comment: I tried counting all possible solutions and choosing the minimal total weight, but it was not fast enough. To be honest I am new in programming and don't know many algorithms. I was thinking perhaps I could distribute the nodes into biggest possible groups (in terms of total weight) and assign them with ascending X values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bottom up approach (through recursion), where for each node you calculate the minimal total weight of the subtree rooted in that node, for each choice of factor (from *X*) for that node.

So if *X* has 10 factors, each node will get 10 calculated weights, each one corresponding to a choice of factor.

As you go up one level from a node to its parent, you collect the same information. When looking at one particular child of that parent, take the two minimal weights calculated for that child (from the 10). Let's say they are for factor *i* and factor *j* respectively. Then if you make the calculation of the total weight for the parent for factor *i*, you must take into account the child's weight that corresponds to factor *j*. In all other cases you can take the one that corresponds to factor *i*.

Here is the idea expressed in JavaScript:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(weight, ...children) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.children = children;
    }
    getMinWeights(factors) {
        // Get the node's own weight for each choice of factor:
        let weights = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < factors.length; i++) {
            weights[i] += factors[i] * this.weight);
        }
        // For each child of this node:
        for (let child of this.children) {
            // Get the min weight corresponding to each factor-choice 
            //    made for the child node
            let childWeights = child.getMinWeights(factors);
            // Get positions (i.e. factor indices) of the 2 smallest results
            let minIndex1 = 0;
            for (let i = 1; i < childWeights.length; i++) {
                if (childWeights[i] < childWeights[minIndex1]) {
                    minIndex1 = i;
                }
            }
            let minIndex2 = minIndex1 > 0 ? 0 : 1;
            for (let i = 0; i < childWeights.length; i++) {
                if (i !== minIndex1 && childWeights[i] < childWeights[minIndex2]) {
                    minIndex2 = i;
                }
            }
            // For each factor choice in this node, determine the best choice 
            //   of factor in the child, and add the corresponding weight 
            //   to the total weight for this node's subtree.
            for (let i = 0; i < childWeights.length; i++) {
                weights[i] += childWeights[i === minIndex1 ? minIndex2 : minIndex1];
            }
        }
        return weights;
    }
}

// Example:
let tree = new Node(1,
    new Node(1), new Node(1), new Node(1,
        new Node(1), new Node(1), new Node(1)
    )
);
let result = tree.getMinWeights([2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(Math.min(...result)); // Return the minimum of the values we got back.
```

This algorithm thus has a time complexity of *O(nm)*, where *n* is the number of nodes, and *m = |X|*.

When the maximum branching factor *b* is known, then you can clip *X* to the *b+2* smallest of them (so *m = b+2*). At any rate *X* can be clipped to the *n* smallest values.

### Get the distribution of X

The above algorithm can be extended to get an optimal distribution of the X factors. For that the minimal weights (per factor, per node) should be stored for each node. Then a new DFS traversal should find the index having the minimum weight, and assign the corresponding X factor to the node. In recursion that index should be excluded from being assigned to the direct children.

Here is the same code with that extension:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(weight, ...children) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.children = children;
    }
    getMinWeights(factors) {
        // Get the node's own weight for each choice of factor:
        let weights = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < factors.length; i++) {
            weights[i] += factors[i] * this.weight;
        }
        // For each child of this node:
        for (let child of this.children) {
            // Get the min weight corresponding to each factor-choice 
            //    made for the child node
            let childWeights = child.getMinWeights(factors);
            // Get positions (i.e. factor indices) of the 2 smallest results
            let minIndex1 = 0;
            for (let i = 1; i < childWeights.length; i++) {
                if (childWeights[i] < childWeights[minIndex1]) {
                    minIndex1 = i;
                }
            }
            let minIndex2 = minIndex1 > 0 ? 0 : 1;
            for (let i = 0; i < childWeights.length; i++) {
                if (i !== minIndex1 && childWeights[i] < childWeights[minIndex2]) {
                    minIndex2 = i;
                }
            }
            // For each factor choice in this node, determine the best choice 
            //   of factor in the child, and add the corresponding weight 
            //   to the total weight for this node's subtree.
            for (let i = 0; i < childWeights.length; i++) {
                weights[i] += childWeights[i === minIndex1 ? minIndex2 : minIndex1];
            }
        }
        // Extra: store the weights with the node
        this.weights = weights;
        
        return weights;
    }
    // Extra: method to distribute the X-factors to each node. Must run after method above.
    assignFactors(factors, excludeIndex=-1) {
        if (excludeIndex === -1) this.getMinWeights(factors); // First do this...
        // Get the index of the factor that results in the minimal weight
        let minIndex = excludeIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0;
        for (let i = 1; i < this.weights.length; i++) {
            if (i !== excludeIndex && this.weights[i] < this.weights[minIndex]) {
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
        // Assign the corresponding factor to this node
        this.factor = factors[minIndex];
        // For each child of this node:
        for (let child of this.children) {
            // recurse, and pass the chosen factor index, so it will not be used
            // for the child:
            child.assignFactors(factors, minIndex);
        }
    }
    toArray() {
        return this.children.length ? [this.factor, this.children.map(child => child.toArray())] : this.factor;
    }
}

// Example:
let tree = new Node(1,
    new Node(1), new Node(1), new Node(1,
        new Node(1), new Node(1), new Node(1)
    )
);
tree.assignFactors([2, 3, 4, 5]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(tree.toArray()));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. The code really helped me understand. Thank you :) btw, tried upvoting you, but it seems I don't have enough reputation

Comment: Could you please help me with finding the distribution of X values on nodes as well? I have been trying for hours, but cant figure it out.

Comment: See addition to answer.